# Problems trying to animate my objects in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make my character move diagonally. My aim is to make him move towards the door depending on which door I click. There are two doors on the screen; top-left door and top-right door. Right now when I click on the top-left door he moves towards that door, but when I click on the top-right door he moves straight. I don't know where I'm going wrong with this and I could really use some help.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //center the character
  function centreThing(obj) {
    //this is the height and width of heartless
    h = $(obj).height();
    w = $(obj).width();
    $(obj).css({
      //this is the height and width of the stage
      //height and width of stage by 2 - height and width of heartless by 2
      top: $('#stage').height() / 2 - h / 2,
      left: $('#stage').width() / 2 - w / 2,
      right: $('#stage').width() / 2 - w / 2
    })
  }
  centreThing('#character');

  //speech
  var progress = 0;
  var txt;

  //click the door to go to next page
  //animate character to the left door
  $('#door1').click(function() {
    $('#character').animate({
      top: 0,
      left: 150
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      complete: function() {
        alert("entered");
      }
    });
  });

  //click the door to go to next page
  //animate character to the right door
  $('#door2').click(function() {
    $('#character').animate({
      top: 0,
      right: 150
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      complete: function() {
        alert("entered");
      }
    });
  });

}); // do not delete this line
```

```css
#character {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 99;
}

#door1 {
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/50x50?text=closeddoor");
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  top: -3px;
  left: 130px;
  z-index: 5;
}

#door1:hover {
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/50x50?text=opendoor");
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  top: -3px;
  left: 130px;
}

#door2 {
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/50x50?text=closeddoor");
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  top: -3px;
  left: 510px;
}

#door2:hover {
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/50x50?text=opendoor");
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  top: -3px;
  left: 510px;
  z-index: 5;
}

#stage {
  position: relative;
  width: 720px;
  height: 480px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MAS340</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="stage">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50?text=character" id="character" class="center">
    <div id='door1'></div>
    <div id='door2'></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Place your scripts before your `</body>` tag and try..

Comment: Is expected result for `#character` to be animated from `#door1` to `#door2`, or from original position to each `#doorN` element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this.Reset the left position on clicking the `#door2`.It happens baecause you have set the left position of the character in `centreThing()`.So on clicking the `#door2` the character has left,right and top value.So it is starting at the left value.I have removed the  left value on clicking on  `#door2` and it worked

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 //center the character
 function centreThing(obj) {
 //this is the height and width of heartless
  h = $(obj).height();
  w = $(obj).width();
  $(obj).css({
   //this is the height and width of the stage
   //height and width of stage by 2 - height and width of heartless by 2
   top: $('#stage').height()/2-h/2,
   left: $('#stage').width()/2-w/2,
   right: $('#stage').width()/2-w/2
  })
 }
 centreThing('#character');
 
 //speech
 var progress = 0;
 var txt;
  
 //click the door to go to next page
 //animate character to the left door
 $('#door1').click(function() {
  $('#character').animate({
   top: 0,
   left: 150
  }, {
   duration: 1000,
   complete: function() {
        alert("entered");
   }
  });
 });
 
 //click the door to go to next page
 //animate character to the right door
 $('#door2').click(function() { 
     $('#character').css({
       'left':''
     }).animate({
   top: 0,
   right: 150
  }, {
   duration: 1000,
   complete: function() {
        alert("entered on 2");
   }
  });
 });

}); // do not delete this line
```

```css
#character {
 position: absolute;
/* bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;*/
 z-index: 99;
}

#door1 {
  background:#F00;
 background-image: url(images/closeddoor.png);
 position: absolute;
 width: 80px;
 height: 60px;
 top: -3px;
 left: 130px;
 z-index: 5; 
}

#door1:hover {
 background-image: url(images/opendoor.png);
 position: absolute;
 width: 80px;
 height: 60px;
 top: -3px;
 left: 130px;
}

#door2 {
  background:#FF0;
 background-image: url(images/closeddoor.png);
 position: absolute;
 width: 80px;
 height: 60px;
 top: -3px;
 left: 510px;
}

#door2:hover {
 background-image: url(images/opendoor.png);
 position: absolute;
 width: 80px;
 height: 60px;
 top: -3px;
 left: 510px;
 z-index: 5;
}

#stage {
 position: relative;
 width: 720px;
 height: 480px;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 100px;
 background-color: black;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 5px;
 border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MAS340</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="stage">
  <img src="images/character.png" id="character" class="center">
  <div id='door1'></div>
  <div id='door2'></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have found the same answer, but could you explain to us why such behavior?